# Issue while Issuing donation receipt (SYSTOPIA Donation Receipts Extension)

Tags: wordpress, receipts, donations

Using [donation receipt SYSTOPIA Donation Receipts Extension](https://github.com/systopia/de.systopia.donrec/issues/118), issuing donation receipt creates this error (and does not complete)

```
Box property calculation requires containing block width
```

I'm running 5.31.0 on WordPress 5.6
I know your extension is not primarily intended for WordPress, yet in our set-up it used to run smoothly.. I guess this is due to 2.0 upgrade? Do you think I could revert to 1.8 or will this crash the DB?
Thanks!